# Trying to write multiple lines to a file but file has only 1 line (or the final values)

Tags: java, file-io

I'm trying to write multiple lines into a file but only one record of `EmpID`, `DeptID` and `Salary` is getting stored. Below is the code snippet.  How do I write multiple lines?

```
case 1:try 
    {
    FileWriter fsalary_specific = new FileWriter(
        new File("Salary_Specific.txt"));
    DeptID = tokens[2];
    String var_2 = tokens[3];
    salary = Double.parseDouble(var_2);
        fsalary_specific.write(EmpID+"   "+DeptID+"   "+salary+"\n");

    fsalary_specific.close();
    } 
    catch (IOException e) 
    {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
    }

    break;
```

Comment: Where you are writing multiple lines? There is no loop which is writing multiple lines.

Comment: This is because you are writing only one of them? In which line do you expect it to write multiple lines?

Comment: I think the switch case condition would be sufficient. Trying to write here fsalary_specific.write(EmpID+"   "+DeptID+"   "+salary+"\n");

Comment: As a side note, you should put your close statement in a finally block

Comment: *"`EmpID`, `DeptID` and `Salary`"* Please learn common Java nomenclature & use it consistently.  That should be something like `empID`, `deptID` and `salary`.

Comment: @ Andrew Thompson done by mistake, Sorry about that

Comment: @SantoshVM  1) Please note that if you put a ' ' after the '@', I do not get a notification. It must be all-one-string.  2) *"Sorry about that "*  Why apologize when you can edit?  ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to open the file in "append" mode if you are re-opening it every time. Pass `true` into the `FileWriter` [constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html#FileWriter%28java.io.File,%20boolean%29) like so:

```
 FileWriter fsalary_specific = new FileWriter(new File("Salary_Specific.txt"), true);
```

Comment: How to wipe out the contents of the file before i add contents to the file?

Comment: perhaps `new File("Salary_specific.txt").delete()` Although I would recommend hanging on to the file handle if youre going to be using it a lot rather than calling `new` every time

Answer (score 2):

See [`FileWriter(File,boolean)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html#FileWriter%28java.io.File,%20boolean%29).  If that does not work for you, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).